# Changing typesetting engine from pdfLaTeX to LuaTeX in TeXnicCenter

Tags: luatex, texniccenter

How does one change the typesetting engine from `pdfLaTeX` to `LuaTeX` in `TeXnicCenter`?  Is it sufficient to just change the path to the `.exe` in `Build->Define Output Profiles`?

Comment: You can try to do this and then read the `log` file to see if LuaTeX was used.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Are you sure you want `luatex` and not `lualatex`? (Note that the engines, as written on the command line, are all lower case.) Also, I would suggest copying the output profile you want to change, so that you can easily switch back to `pdflatex`.

Comment: You should first copy the output profile “LaTeX ⇨ PDF” into a new profile “LuaLaTeX ⇨ PDF” and _in this new profile you can replace `pdflatex.exe` with `lualatex.exe`_.

Answer (score 5):

If you install TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta 1, the option to compile with LuaLaTeX is already available as follows:

[image]

Note that TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta 1 (either 32 or 64 bit version) still does NOT support Unicode even though it claims to support UTF-8. That is its feature!

Comment: TeXnicCenter 2.0 does support UTF8, at least here by me! It must be another local issue on your computer.

Comment: @Speravir: I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that should be enough- as @Sigur says, you'll be able to tell by reading the `.log` file.

When I compile the MWE `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}hello world\end{document}` using `pdflatex` the first line of the `.log` file is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) (format=pdflatex 2012.12.20)  29 DEC 2012 09:32
```

and when I compile using `lualatex` the first line of the `.log` file is

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012062812 (TeX Live 2012) (format=lualatex 2012.12.20)  29 DEC 2012 09:35
```