# Help with MetaPost and Metaobj with latex

Tags: pdftex, luatex, metapost, metafun

Kind help with two examples to do metapost and metaobj in latex running from Texicenter.

what packages to include and program two examples

I read through book not able to understand.

First

```
input metafun

draw fulldiamond scaled 1cm withcolor blue;
```

second

```
input metaobj

nczigzag(a)(b);
nczigzag(a)(b)
"angleA(-90)","angleB(120)",
"linetension(0.8)","coilwidth(2mm)",
"linearc(0.1mm)";
drawObj(a,b);
```

Below code not working help

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
input test.mp
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

where test.mp

```
beginfig(1) ;
draw fulldiamond scaled 1cm withcolor blue ;
endfig ;
end ;
```

Then ran it in in LuLatex but errors and output not coming

second if in the above in above instead of test.mp as above code

if we have `test.mp` as

```
input metaobj
beginfig(1) ;
newCircle.a(btex A etex) ;
newCircle.b(btex B etex) ;
a.c=origin ;
b.c=(3cm,2cm) ;
nczigzag(a)(b) ;
nczigzag(a)(b) "angleA(-90)","angleB(120)",
               "linetension(0.8)",
               "coilwidth(2mm)", "linearc(0.1mm)" ;
drawObj(a,b) ;
endfig ;
end ;
```

How to run without errors Kind help

Comment: You will find an answer to your first question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454934/how-to-even-start-learning-metapost-using-windows/454935#454935

Comment: Is it possible to create frame like slide (like beamer slides) when we fun as metafun IF so help with an example with above two in two different frames

Comment: This is a new question. Please ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

## MetaFun

MetaFun are not macros which can be input, but it is another format (sort of like Plain TeX vs. LaTeX).  So to run a file with MetaFun you have to preload the format with `mpost '&metafun' test.mp`.

```metapost
beginfig(1) ;
draw fulldiamond scaled 1cm withcolor blue ;
endfig ;
end ;
```

[image]

## MetaObj

Your MetaObj example can't work because you are trying to connect objects `a` and `b` which do not exist.  I just made two circles and placed them somewhere.

```metapost
input metaobj

beginfig(1) ;
newCircle.a(btex A etex) ;
newCircle.b(btex B etex) ;
a.c=origin ;
b.c=(3cm,2cm) ;
nczigzag(a)(b) ;
nczigzag(a)(b) "angleA(-90)","angleB(120)",
               "linetension(0.8)",
               "coilwidth(2mm)", "linearc(0.1mm)" ;
drawObj(a,b) ;
endfig ;
end ;
```

[image]

## Embedding the figures in a document

You tagged the question with [luatex](/questions/tagged/luatex), so we can use `luamplib`.  Since MetaFun is actually a superset of plain MetaPost, we can globally switch the format to MetaFun using `\mplibsetformat{metafun}`.  We also add some convenience code in `\everymplib` and `\everyendmplib` so we don't have to type `beginfig` and `endfig` every time and the picture will always be in horizontal mode.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\mplibsetformat{metafun}

\everymplib{
  verbatimtex \leavevmode etex ;
  beginfig(0) ;
}
\everyendmplib{
  endfig ;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    draw fulldiamond scaled 1cm withcolor blue ;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input metaobj ;

    newCircle.a(btex A etex) ;
    newCircle.b(btex B etex) ;
    a.c=origin ;
    b.c=(3cm,2cm) ;
    nczigzag(a)(b) ;
    nczigzag(a)(b) "angleA(-90)","angleB(120)",
                   "linetension(0.8)",
                   "coilwidth(2mm)", "linearc(0.1mm)" ;
    drawObj(a,b) ;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to create frame like slide (like beamer slides) when we fun as metafun IF so help with an example with above two in two different frames

Comment: @sriram In LaTeX or in plain MetaPost?